# If not hydrogenated, how are spreads from olive oil made?

Tags: oil

I read that many spreads are non hydrogenated, so then how are they made solid?

Comment: 100% olive oil? Many products contain small amounts of olive oil in addition to whatever else they are primarily made of.

Answer (score 1):

Olive oil contains a certain percentage of saturated fats, which are probably separated out and used. Alternatively, there is a process called interestification that is sometimes used to make more solid forms of non-solid fats without hydrogenation.

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for sure, but it's possible that it's simply achieved through temperature -- olive oil will solidify in your refrigerator.

(I make basil infused olive oil, which I then keep in the fridge.  You have to keep it in a jar so you can extract it, because it won't pour at fridge temps)